# A figure of speech combining two phrases

Tags: poetry, terminology

I have read somewhere that it is typical of poems such as Nibelungenlied to use a figure of speech which in fact merges two phrases into one by the mean of a common word. An example could be the following:

*And then I ate the apple was red as blood*

A proper example of this can be found in Nibelungenlied (Adventure 20, 1184, 1-2), where we have

> man sach
>
> Ortwin von Mezze | ce Rvedgeren sprach

which means

> one saw
>
> Ortwin von Metz | to Rüdiger said

So, is there a name for this figure of speech? Is it a typical figure of other *archaic* poems such as Beowulf or am I confusing?

Comment: Just edited to add an example from Nibelungenlied

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In German, this type of phrase is known as a "Wendesatz". (Unfortunately, I couldn't find an online dictionary that explains the term, let alone a translation.) Below are a few examples. Some of them don't work well in translation.

- "Ich liebe **meine Frau** liebt mich nicht mehr": I love **my wife** no longer loves me.
- "Ich hasse **egoisten** kümmern sich nur um sich selbst, nie um mich.": I hate **egoists** care only about themselves, never about me.
- "Erst lehren sie ihre Kinder **zu sprechen** bei Tisch wird ihnen verboten.": First they teach their children **to speak** during meals is forbidden (i.e. they forbid their children to speak during meals).
- "Ich werde niemals **reich** mir doch mal den Kaviar": I'll never be **rich**/**pass on** the caviar. (reich: 1. [adjective] rich; 2. imperative of the verb "reichen")

There is a long list of German examples in the blog post [Gedankensprünge durch Wendesätze](https://multisprech.org/2016/11/03/gedankenspruenge-durch-wendesaetze/) (3 November 2016).

**Update**: The "Wendesatz" looks a lot like a special subclass of the [**apo koinou construction**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apo_koinou_construction), which Wikipedia defines as "a blend of two clauses through a lexical word which has two syntactical functions, one in each of the blended clauses." Here is an example: "There was a door led into the kitchen" (Hemingway). This sentence looks like a normal sentence from which "that" ("a door that ...") has been deleted. Wendesätze, however, don't even try to be grammatical.

Comment: That is possibly the word I was looking for! The fact that we are not able to find anything about it, anyway, could mean that it is not a broadly known figure of speech, though I would say that it should be included among those.